# activeMQ master/slave cluster with zookeeper

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

I have my activeMQ connected to zookeeper (a cluster of 5 zookeepers),  in the config file "activemq.xml",  I have

```
<persistenceAdapter>
            <replicatedLevelDB
                directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"
                replicas="3"
                bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:0"
                zkAddress="blablabla:2181"
                        zkPassword="password"
                zkPath="/activemq/leveldb-stores"
                hostname="blabla"
            />
  </persistenceAdapter>
```

now I have activeMQ-server1 started,  successfully become the master;     activeMQ-server2 with the same "activemq.xml"  config file,  successfully become the slave;      activeMQ-server3 with the same "activemq.xml"  config file,  successfully become the slave, but kicks out activeMQ-server2  (start to give connection error)

I think I put the wrong number for replicas,  I changed all the 3 config files with  "replicas="4"",  still not work

what would be the correct  replicas number  with  3 activeMQ servers,  or I am wrong with some other parts.  (I only have 1 zookeeper listed in config, since the 5 zookeepers can connect to each other, already a cluster there)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to list all zookeeper servers in the zkAddress portion, `zkAddress="zoo1.example.org:2181,zoo2.example.org:2181,zoo3.example.org:2181"`, taken from [activemq replicated levelDB](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html)

Answer (score 0):

The replicas value is the number of activemq nodes, not the number of zookeeper nodes. So if you have 3 amq nodes, set replicas="3", not more. http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html :

```
Replicas property :
The number of nodes that will exist in the cluster.
At least (replicas/2)+1 nodes must be online to avoid service outage.
```

Another thing, all amq nodes in the cluster must get the same name (MyBroker below):

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="MyBroker" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
```